# Firestore React-Native - 'collectionPath' must be a string value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to convert the Integer array state into a String array to access the collection.
When I'm Restarting the app it shows this error [image: Error]
But somehow, when I'm saving my code it refreshes and shows the correct information without errors.

`getJobs():`

```
let length = 0;
        let jobData = [];
        const data = await firestore()
            .collection(groupID)
            .doc('jobs-list')
            .get()
            .then((value) => {
                length = Object.keys(value.data()).length;
                for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    jobData.push(value.data()[i]);
                }
            })

        setJobsNumbers(jobData);
    JSON.stringify(jobsNumbers);
    
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                console.log(jobData[i])
                const job = await firestore()
                    .collection(groupID)
                    .doc('jobs')
                    .collection(jobsNumbers[i])
                    .get()
                    .then(querySnapshot => {
                        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                            console.log('Job ID: ', documentSnapshot.id, documentSnapshot.data());
                        });
                    });
            };
```

`useEffect:`

```
useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = firestore()
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(currentUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
                setGroupID(documentSnapshot.data().group);
            });
        getJobs();

        // Stop listening for updates when no longer required
        return () => subscriber();
    }, [currentUser.uid]);
```

`jobsNumber` is not undefined or null

Comment: do console.log(groupID) just before you start firestore().collection(groupID)... let's see the value of groupID. If Firebase is correct (that groupID is *), then you know it is not an issue with Firebase (or how you use it), but an issue that will involve you debugging your app's code.

Comment: It shows `undefined`. I'm getting the groupID from firestore inside an `useEffect` hook and calling the `getJobs()` after the setGroupID. (`getJobs()` is the code above)

Comment: do console.log(documentSnapshot.data().group) just before `setGroupID(documentSnapshot.data().group)` let's see if the snapshot data actually has a valid groupID. I think I know where the issue is from. This comment box can't contain, let me explain in answer.

Comment: `getJobs()- console.log` shows `undefined` and `console.log(documentSnapshot.data().group)` shows `840403`, which is the correct data.

Comment: I think the problem is that `getJobs` runs first, and I don't know how to make it run after the `subcriber` gets the `groupID`.

Comment: Oh, put the call of `getJobs` inside the callback of onSnapshot then. That is immediately after `setGroupID`.  but then it will be calling `getJobs` every time the user document changes. I got carried away while typing an answer. I was trying to explain that maybe currentUser could be null at app load, but that seemed not to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the call of `getJobs` inside the callback of onSnapshot then. That is immediately after `setGroupID`. This way the collectionPath (`groupID`) must have been set before that code is running.